# Make Solr server accessible on network

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, solr, centos6.4

So I've installed Solr on a linux server and I want to access it from another web server and/or my computer.

From the Solar Server, I can see that it's running

```
[root@solr ~]# wget -qO- http://localhost:8983/solr




<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="solr-admin.css">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"></link>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"></link>
<title>Welcome to Solr</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to Solr!</h1>
<a href="."><img border="0" align="right" height="78" width="142" src="admin/solr_small.png" alt="Solr"/></a>


<a href="admin/">Solr Admin</a>


</body>
</html>
```

However, plugging `http://192.168.1.19:8983/solr/` into my browser, or pinging from my web server, fails to connect.  How do I make Solr accessible to other devices on my network?

---

```
# netstat -anp | grep :8983
tcp        0      0 :::8983                     :::*                        LISTEN      15138/java
```

---

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.19 8983
Trying 192.168.1.19...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.19: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Could it be a firewall blocking tcp 8983? Either on your solr host or in your network between client and server?

Comment: Check iptables config on your server.

Answer (score 3):

How are you running Solr? Under Tomcat? I will assume so, since I know how to restrict to `localhost` under Tomcat & if you just undo what I do to restrict it, then you can network your Solr install.

In my case, I disallow Tomcat from dealing with the outside world—I prefer Apache reverse proxying—so I do the following.

I edit the Tomcat `server.xml` over here:

```
/etc/tomcat6/server.xml
```

I look for the `Connector` settings and add `address="127.0.0.1"` which locks the Tomcat install to 127.0.0.1 (aka: localhost)

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           address="127.0.0.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

So in your case, I would just remove the `address` setting like so:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But then again, no idea how your Solr instance is being served.  And if it’s not being served via Tomcat, then someone else needs to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the Solr server is listening to the correct interfaces ?

What's the output of :

```
netstat -anp | grep :8983
```

If you see `127.0.0.1:8983` or `::1:8983` that's because your server don't listen to the outside world. You can correct this by editing the configuration of the webserver you are using.

Otherwise, if you see `0.0.0.0:8983` the issue may be somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the output.

Comment: Ok, now can you precise what kind of error it is : A conection Timeout, or a connection refused ?
If you issue a `telnet 192.168.1.9 8983` on your client, what's the output ?
If it's a Timeout, it should be a firewall or connectivity issue.
If it's a Refuse, the server explicitely refused the connection: the firewall or the application explicitely refused it.

Comment: The connection is being refused. How do I allow it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `datastax`, update (in `cassandra.yaml`) the `listen_address:` and `rpc_address:` to the IP address of the machine and it will work.

By default it's mentioned as `localhost`.